# How to start node js server on online server?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I start my pet Project, using technologies are

1. **Front end - Angular JS**
2. **Back end - MongoDB**
3. **Server Layer - Node.js**

I am done some Progress for local system.

In local system I am using `Node app.js` to run the server.

For MongoDB For local system I am using commands

```
Mongod
```

How to do all things on Online Server? How to start Node js server and How start MongoDB server?

Comment: A slightly belated Welcome to StackOverflow, ummm @stackover flow. Sure you have asked a few questions and accepted a couple of answers already. But what you need to understand here is that questions like this are far too broad for this site to provide a complete answer for. For one, there are "many" ways to do things you are asking for, and any responses are just largely peoples opinions of things you should use or do with such a broad scope. I would suggest some reading about hosting services for deployment ( much out there on the interwebs ) and other resources you can find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can SSH & FTP to server, first upload your files, then use a terminal software like PUTTY.exe to create a connection, and do the same.

Comment: I think you need to understand that "what is being asked here" is actually a "much broader question" of *"How to even start deploying my application remotely?"* Which is why we would like the OP to reconsider their question and maybe ask something specific. This does not really answer that, nor is it really an answer at all. When you have the privellege to "comment" then you can comment. But leave answers to real answers, and an answer is really not appropriate here right now. See how long my "comment" can be?

Comment: I stand corrected. Maybe? Well it's accepted as an answer anyhow. So it might have been exactly what the OP was really asking in their own way. But almost certainly off-topic nonetheless.